# How to check if a network path exist?

Tags: python, linux, networking

What is the best way to know if a network path(e.g. //192.168.1.1/test) exist using python in linux?

Comment: Programming questions go to Stackoverflow.com

Comment: As in an interface / route, or scanning neighbors?

Comment: It looks like he may mean a Windows UNC path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "path" you mean an internet URL, you'll want to look at the urllib module.

```
from urllib import urlopen
try:
    urlopen(path)
except IOError:
    pass # does not exist
else:
    pass # does exist
```

If by "path" you mean a Windows UNC, then you'll want to use the os module.

```
import os
os.path.isdir(path)
```

Note, I've found the Windows UNC paths somewhat flakey. Depending on your network setup and permissions, they may or may not be accessible.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What i want is that if a user enter a network path(a shared folder path), before going for further processing, i want to verify that if that path really exist or not?

Comment: I am using os.stat function which throws an exception if network device is not available, or network path is not found. Even attempting to open the file with "open" metod also throws an exception. But these approaches may not reveal whether the network device is down or file not found. For precise checks, you may have to utilize psutil's network interface functions as an option.