# Convert command line command to usual python string

Tags: python, command-line

Sorry for this stupid question in advance.

I have a usual command:

'if not exist \\ip_here\C$\chromedriver.exe do_stuff'

and I want to convert it to python script:

```
os.system(r"if not exist \\" + ip + "\\C$\\" + file + " exit 1") == 1
```

But it does not work.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Can you clarify what "does not work" means? Do you get an error message from the script, an error message from the system, does it do a different thing than you intended? Also I've noticed you made several edits to the line after posting, completely changing what strings are being appended to each other. We need to see the actual line you are executing.

Comment: Nothing happened, I guess some problem with  backslashes...

Comment: If what you've given us is the code you're using then you're missing a space before `"do_stuff"` in the resulting string, so you're creating `if exist \\[IP]\C$\chromedriver.exedo_stuff`. *Note to people reading this comment later: The line was changed again since I said this.*

Comment: Sorry for this editing, and thank you for the help

Comment: I did it, looks like it is ok.

Comment: @Sreawqy, ...that said, [how to check if a network path exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2578177/how-to-check-if-a-network-path-exist) is a better way to solve this problem.

Comment: What is raw string?

Comment: I'm sorry -- I misread; you already _are_ using a raw string (that's what the `r` before the first `"` is).

Comment: (only that first substring is raw -- the others don't have a `r` before the opening `"` -- but that's fine, because in the others you're doubling up your backslashes).